# Как получить значения запрет отгрузки для контрагента в 1с?

Tags: 1с

Имеется следующий запрос:

```
Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗРЕШЕННЫЕ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
                   |    МАКСИМУМ(КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Представление) КАК Представление,
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Ссылка КАК Ссылка
                   |ПОМЕСТИТЬ Телефон
                   |ИЗ
                   |    Справочник.Контрагенты.КонтактнаяИнформация КАК КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация
                   |ГДЕ
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Вид.Наименование = ""Телефон""
                   |
                   |СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Ссылка
                   |;
                   |
                   |////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   |ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗРЕШЕННЫЕ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
                   |    МАКСИМУМ(КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Представление) КАК Представление,
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Ссылка КАК Ссылка
                   |ПОМЕСТИТЬ ЭлектроннаяПочта
                   |ИЗ
                   |    Справочник.Контрагенты.КонтактнаяИнформация КАК КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация
                   |ГДЕ
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Вид.Наименование = ""Электронная почта""
                   |
                   |СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Ссылка
                   |;
                   |
                   |////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   |ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗРЕШЕННЫЕ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
                   |    МАКСИМУМ(КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Представление) КАК Представление,
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Ссылка КАК Ссылка
                   |ПОМЕСТИТЬ ЮридическийАдрес
                   |ИЗ
                   |    Справочник.Контрагенты.КонтактнаяИнформация КАК КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация
                   |ГДЕ
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Вид.Наименование = ""Юридический адрес""
                   |
                   |СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО
                   |    КонтрагентыКонтактнаяИнформация.Ссылка
                   |;
                   |
                   |////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   |ВЫБРАТЬ
                   |    РасчетыСКлиентамиОстатки.СуммаОстаток + РасчетыСКлиентамиОстатки.ОтгружаетсяОстаток КАК ОстатокДолга,
                   |    РасчетыСКлиентамиОстатки.АналитикаУчетаПоПартнерам.Контрагент КАК Контрагент
                   |ПОМЕСТИТЬ Лимиты
                   |ИЗ
                   |    РегистрНакопления.РасчетыСКлиентами.Остатки(
                   |            ,
                   |            АналитикаУчетаПоПартнерам В
                   |                (ВЫБРАТЬ
                   |                    АналитикаПоПартнерам.КлючАналитики КАК КлючАналитики
                   |                ИЗ
                   |                    РегистрСведений.АналитикаУчетаПоПартнерам КАК АналитикаПоПартнерам)) КАК РасчетыСКлиентамиОстатки
                   |;
                   |
                   |////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   |ВЫБРАТЬ
                   |    МАКСИМУМ(ДоговорыКонтрагентов.ДопустимаяСуммаЗадолженности) КАК ДопустимаяСуммаЗадолженности,
                   |    ДоговорыКонтрагентов.Контрагент КАК Контрагент
                   |ПОМЕСТИТЬ МакимальнаяСуммаЗадолженности
                   |ИЗ
                   |    Справочник.ДоговорыКонтрагентов КАК ДоговорыКонтрагентов
                   |
                   |СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО
                   |    ДоговорыКонтрагентов.Контрагент
                   |;
                   |
                   |////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   |ВЫБРАТЬ
                   |    Контрагенты.Наименование КАК Наименование,
                   |    ЕСТЬNULL(Контрагенты.НаименованиеПолное, """") КАК НаименованиеПолное,
                   |    ЕСТЬNULL(Контрагенты.ИНН, """") КАК ИНН,
                   |    ЕСТЬNULL(Телефон.Представление, """") КАК Телефон,
                   |    ЕСТЬNULL(ЭлектроннаяПочта.Представление, """") КАК ЭлектроннаяПочта,
                   |    ЕСТЬNULL(ЮридическийАдрес.Представление, """") КАК ЮридическийАдрес,
                   |    ПРЕДСТАВЛЕНИЕ(ЕСТЬNULL(МакимальнаяСуммаЗадолженности.ДопустимаяСуммаЗадолженности, 0) - ЕСТЬNULL(Лимиты.ОстатокДолга, 0)) КАК ОстатокДопустимогоКредита,
                   |    ПРЕДСТАВЛЕНИЕ(ЕСТЬNULL(МакимальнаяСуммаЗадолженности.ДопустимаяСуммаЗадолженности, 0)) КАК ДопустимаяСуммаЗадолженности
                   |ИЗ
                   |    Справочник.Контрагенты КАК Контрагенты
                   |        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Телефон КАК Телефон
                   |        ПО (Телефон.Ссылка = Контрагенты.Ссылка)
                   |        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ ЭлектроннаяПочта КАК ЭлектроннаяПочта
                   |        ПО (ЭлектроннаяПочта.Ссылка = Контрагенты.Ссылка)
                   |        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ ЮридическийАдрес КАК ЮридическийАдрес
                   |        ПО (ЮридическийАдрес.Ссылка = Контрагенты.Ссылка)
                   |        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ МакимальнаяСуммаЗадолженности КАК МакимальнаяСуммаЗадолженности
                   |        ПО (МакимальнаяСуммаЗадолженности.Контрагент = Контрагенты.Ссылка)
                   |        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Лимиты КАК Лимиты
                   |        ПО (Лимиты.Контрагент = Контрагенты.Ссылка)";
```

Как добавить запрос на получение значения Запрет отгрузки клиента (Клиенту запрещенео отгрузка)? Да/Нет (true, false)?